# Using Switch to Automate Adding User to Groups. Active Directory Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to automate adding new users to their required groups based on their Branch and Department that they work in,. ive got that working, but i also want to add some optional sub Departments that users may or may not be apart of and i just want to add any user that is a part of these sub Department get added to the end array containing all the groups the user needs to be apart of.

so a user would be a part of a branch and a department, and then optionally part of a sub Department.

what I'm not sure how to do is how to switch these sub Departments so that they are not mutually Exclusive, i.e  a user would have 'account manager' and 'Company Vehicle ' Sub Departments, and these Sub Departments would each have a couple Groups that would be applied to the end as $SubGroups

basically I want the sub Departments to be optional, but also can select multiple of them at a time, so that anyone after me can just add anything they want to it and the script won't break

so, for example, these are  sub Departments

- Account Managers
- Internal Sales Support
- School Sales
- Staff with a company Vehicle
- RemoteAccess

  each of these Sub Departments would have a couple of Groups that could be applied to the end as $SubGroups

the reference groups at the end automate group membership, by comparing the reference groups (the groups the user should be in) with the groups that the user is currently in. then add/ remove as necessary.
i already have this part, i just chopped it off the end to make it a bit smaller.

*This is what I have so far:*

```
$User = $_.user
$Department = $_.OrgDepartmentName
$Branch = $_.Branch
Switch ($Department) {
    Sales {
        $DepartmentGroups = @(
            "Sales Team"
        )
    }
    Services {
        $DepartmentGroups = @(
            "Services Team"
        )
    }
    Admin {
        $DepartmentGroups = @(
            "Admin Team"
        )
    }
}
Switch ($Branch) {
    Christchurch {
        $BranchGroups = @(
            "Christchurch Team",
            "Christchurch Admin"
        )
    }
    Auckland {
        $BranchGroups = @(
            " Auckland Team",
            " Auckland Admin"
        )
    }
    Wellington {
        $BranchGroups = @(
            "Wellington Team",
            "Wellington Admin"
        )
    }
    Dunedin {
        $BranchGroups = @(
            "Dunedin Team",
            "Dunedin Admin"
        )
    }
}
$AllCompanyGroups = @(
    "All Company"
    "All Staff"
)
$UserGroups = $AllCompanyGroups + $DepartmentGroups + $BranchGroups + $Subgroups
$UserGroups = $ReferenceGroups
$UserGroups
```

Comment: What is the question? It doesn't look like anything is wrong

Comment: i already have the User Groups comparison part done, what I'm not sure is Adding a 4th part to $usergroups, that would have a switch that can trigger multiple times, as opposed to being exclusive like the ones i have, ie if somone has a company car, and is an Account manager i want to add the switches for that, im not sure how to form non exclusive switches.

Comment: See `get-help while`? Do you want it to loop a specific amount of times? `get-help for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below should do what your are looking to do. You still would need a way of generating the items for $Selection

```
 [System.Collections.ArrayList]$SubGroup = @()
 $Selection = "Account Managers", "Internal Sales Support"

 Switch ($Selection) {
    "Account Managers" {$SubGroup.Add("AMGroup1")
                        $SubGroup.Add("AMGroup2")}
    "Internal Sales Support" {$SubGroup.Add("Internal Sales Support")}
    "School Sales" {$SubGroup.Add("School Sales")}
    "Staff with a company Vehicle" {$SubGroup.Add("CarGroup1")
                                    $SubGroup.Add("CarGroup2")}
    }

 $SubGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for advice on next steps.  If I'm reading this right you want to compare $UserGroups to $ReferenceGroups, to see which groups the user needs to be added to or removed from.

If I've got that right you can try `Compare-Object` it's awesome and super easy to compare arrays. Like:

```
$Compare = Compare-Object $ReferenceGroups $UserGroups
$Adds    = ( $Compare | Where-Object{ $_.SideIndicator = '<=' } ).InputObject
$Removes = ( $Compare | Where-Object{ $_.SideIndicator = '=>' } ).InputObject
```

If you just want to append $UserGroups with $ReferenceGroups you can use the += operator.

```
$UserGroups += $ReferenceGroups
```

> Note: It's generally better to use an ArrayList when appending,
>   but that's another topic.

As it is now $ReferenceUsers would be null, so `$UserGroups = $ReferenceGroups` would end up nulling `$UserGroups`.

Also, not a functional issue, but given that you aren't appending array's for department or branch groups, you may want to put `Break` statements in each switch block like:

```
Christchurch {
    $BranchGroups = @(
        "Christchurch Team",
        "Christchurch Admin"
    )
    Break
}
```

This will stop unnecessary evaluations.

Comment: apologies, ive already got that part, but chopped it off to make the script smaller, i have clarified my question so as to avoid futrue confusion, thank you though, what you've provided is better than the roundabout way i had so ill look at that next